# How do you work with non-geographic polygon vector data in Python?

Tags: python, vector, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

This is probably a fairly basic question, but I'm quite new.
I have a load of csv files that contain polygon vertices. I'm trying to extract features from the data I have, and I'm trying to find the most efficient way of doing this.

Each csv file contains one row per polygon, amounting to thousands of rows per csv file. I have a few hundred csv files. Each row contains a vector of vertices in the form [x1:y1:x2:y2:...xn:yn].

I'm not sure why the data is in this form (it's an open-source dataset) and it's not so much the volume of work that I'm worried about, so much as trying to figure out the best way to extract features such as:
-length of edges
-location of centroids
etc.

There seems to be a lot of stuff in libraries for geospatial data, but this is not geospatial and I'm reluctant to go down the shapefile route and use relevant libraries in case it really messes with the data. My x and y coordinates represent positions on large bitmaps, not actual maps.

Has anyone done any work with polygon data and can you signpost me to some good techniques? Otherwise I'm looking at maybe building everything from scratch and putting my own maths in, which seems fairly daunting at this stage. I have a biological sciences background. I guess technically I'm not limited to Python.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you possibly provide a link to the dataset?

Comment: Sure - they're here: https://stonybrookmedicine.app.box.com/v/cnn-nuclear-segmentations-2019/folder/79467753034

Answer (score 0):

> trying to figure out the best way to extract features such as: -length of edges -location of centroids etc.

It's always debatable whether some way is *the best way*, so here's just one way: You could use [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html).

```
# first let's read one of those files into a list of dictionaries (one per row)
import csv
rows = [*csv.DictReader(open('12001_12001_4000_4000_0.2527_1-features.csv'))]
# rows[0] e. g. is the first data line:
# {'AreaInPixels': '131', 'PhysicalSize': '131', 'Polygon': '[15795.0:12001.0:…]'}
# now convert the 'Polygon' string to a list of coordinates, [15795.0, 12001.0, …]
row = rows[0]
coords = eval(row['Polygon'].replace(':', ','))
# now Shapely comes into play
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
# pass the list of coordinates converted to a list of coordinate pairs
p = Polygon([*map(lambda x, y: (x, y), *[iter(coords)]*2)])
# we now have the Polygon object and can use Shapely's attributes
print(p.length)
print(p.centroid)
```